# How to access external dll function?

Tags: dll, external, lnk2001

Im busy to create a dll  (in Windows, with VS 6.0).
That dll have some functions who call some other functions from a external dll.

In the main dll I have added :

```
include "external_lib.h"
```

But when I try to compile get this error:

> main_lib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _My_external_Function

It seems that the main dll do not find the external dll...

In `external_lib.h` there is no assign to "C:\myprg\external_lib.dll"

How can i assign the name of that dll ?

I understand that, if the directory is not defined, it search into "C:\windows\system", but how to declare the name of the external dll ? ( here "external_lib.dll" )

Must i declare it in main_lib.h or external_lib.h ?

Comment: Many thanks to answer. But where to add it and how ? How can i convert a dll into lib ?

Comment: You don't convert it - an external dll should have a header file and a lib. Then you `#include` the header and add the name of the lib and the folder containing it to your project properties in the linker section.

Comment: I do not have the lib file. It is a library (portaudio) with only the dll and the header file (i have compiled it with mingw). Or maybe is it possible to produce a lib file with mingw ?

Comment: "add the name of the lib and the folder containing it to your project properties in the linker section.". ok, thanks, gonna try with dll2lib shareware. See you later

Answer (score 0):

After a big fight, I get it.
First I had to find the code of the external dll and recompile it to have his lib file ( all the tools like dll2lib do not work ).
Then include in link-import that external.lib, compile and it works.

Im happy.